# Retrieve Prop Values from Imported Custom Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a custom component (TextButton) and I have packaged it inside another component (ContainedButton). I'm currently attempting to style ContainedButton. However, I want to access the value of a prop of TextButton (theme) and use the value when styling ContainedButton.

ContainedButton:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextButton from './TextButton';

class ContainedButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const { style } = this.props;

        return (
            <TextButton {...this.props} style={[styles.containedButtonStyle, style]} />
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    containedButtonStyle: {
        backgroundColor: (TextButton prop theme)
        padding: 2,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5
    }
};

export default ContainedButton;
```

In the parentheses next to 'backgroundColor', I want to insert the value of the theme prop located in TextButton. How would I achieve something like this?

TextButton (in case it's needed):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class TextButton extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount() {}

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.theme !== this.props.theme) {
            this.determineTheme(newProps.theme);
        }
        if (newProps.size !== this.props.size) {
            this.determineSize(newProps.size);
        }
    }

    // set the theme
    determineTheme = function (theme) {
        if (theme === 'primary') {
            return {
                color: '#0098EE'
            };
        } else if (theme === 'secondary') {
            return {
                color: '#E70050'
            };
        } else if (theme === 'default') {
            return {
                color: '#E0E0E0'
            };
        } 

        return {
            color: '#E0E0E0'
        };
    }

    // set the size
    determineSize = function (size) {
        if (size === 'small') {
            return {
                fontSize: 16
            };
        } else if (size === 'medium') {
            return {
                fontSize: 22
            };
        } else if (size === 'large') {
            return {
                fontSize: 28
            };
        }

        return {
            fontSize: 22
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { onPress, children, theme, size, style } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={style}>
                <Text style={[this.determineTheme(theme), this.determineSize(size)]}>{children}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

TextButton.propTypes = {
    onPress: PropTypes.func,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    theme: PropTypes.string,
    size: PropTypes.string
};

export default TextButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of `theme` in the same way you get the value of `style`:

```
const { theme } = this.props;
```

Or combine them into a single statement:

```
const { style, theme } = this.props;
```

Comment: But theme is a prop of TextButton, not ContainedButton. I want to use the value of theme from TextButton in my ContainedButton class. If I assign theme to this.props, won't that make it a prop of ContainedButton?

Comment: @yesar `theme` is also a prop of `ContainedButton`. All props are passed from parent to child. This means that `ContainedButton` passes `theme` and `style` to `TextButton`. In this case, they are passed from the props of `ContainedButton`. Note that it impossible read the props of a child component. It isn't even necessary because the child component's props **always** come from the parent anyway, so the parent component already has the values for those props and doesn't need to read them from anywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just tried out your suggestion and everything is working smoothly. Thank you!